# How do I get the Quick Start Project to build and execute?

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to get the Google Quickstart project to work on Android.
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android. I notice there are lots of similar questions on this- and wondered if there was a sample project anywhere that does work?

I followed the instructions but I get an error when it starts up: 
06-10 00:15:04.904: E/AndroidRuntime(16613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 00:15:04.904: E/AndroidRuntime(16613): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential

Which refers to this line:

```
  credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should target an API level with Google APIs and make sure that Google APIs client library jars are on your build path.

Comment: Did that but now I have another problem. doesn't seem to auth. but thanks for help.